# Surjective total computable functions are not r.e

Tags: diagonalization, computability

I want to prove by diagonalization that the set of surjective total computable functions from N to N is not recursively enumerable. I know that the result is trivial using Rice's theorem, but I am trying to prove it only by a direct diagonalization argument. However, supposing that we can enumerate the functions of the set, I am unable to construct a proper surjective and total function that cannot belong to the set.

Comment: Hint: if these functions were r.e., we would have a computable surjection $g : \mathbb{N} \to \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \mid f$ is a total recursive function$\}$. You can apply a diagonalisation argument from here.

Comment: I do not understand : g is not a surjection from N to N.

Comment: Or rather, I should say that the uncurried form of $g$ is a total computable function, not $g$ itself. So the function $(n, m) \mapsto g(n)(m)$ is computable.

Comment: Ok, I see how (by taking Cantor's encoding and using projections for example) we get to a surjective total computable function from N to N. But still where does the contradiction lie ? We could write $\phi (x) = \psi (proj_1(x), proj_2(x)) = \psi(x_0, x)$ for some $x_0$ (where $\psi$ enumerates our set), and then take x to be $x_0$, so that $\phi(x_0) = \psi(proj_1(x_0), proj_2(x_0)) = \psi(x_0, x_0)$. But still I don't see why it couldn't be the case.

Comment: When we want to show that $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is not countable, we assume there is a surjection $g : \mathbb{N} \to (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N})$ and derive a contradiction by considering the function $n \mapsto g(n)(n) + 1$. Essentially the same argument applies here.

Comment: I agree on the basic idea. I just dont see how to implement it rigorously here. Because we cannot just take g to be our enumeration function here, otherwise there is no reason $n \mapsto g(n)(n)+1$ is surjective right ? Maybe I'm confused here

Comment: Moreover, the enumeration function might be partial computable, so $n \mapsto g(n)(n) + 1$ may not even be total computable. So this doesn't seem to work straightforwardly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use a diagonalization argument to prove something even a bit stronger:

Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of natural numbers (including $0,$ for convenience).

Given any sequence
$$\begin{align}&S_0:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, \\
&S_1:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, \\
&S_2:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, \\
&...\end{align}$$
of (total) functions in which every surjective recursive function appears at least once, the function $S: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ defined by
$$S(n, k) = S_n(k)$$
is not recursive.

Assume, aiming at a contradiction, that $S$ is recursive.

Define a function $f: \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ by setting

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
S(n/2,n)+1, &\text{if }n\text{ is even,} \\
(n-1)/2, &\text{if }n\text{ is odd.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is recursive and surjective, so there exists $e\in\mathbb N$ such that $f = S_e.$

It follows that

$$\begin{align}f(2e) &= S(e,2e)+1 &\text{(by the definition of }f\text{)}\\
 &= S_e(2e) + 1 &\text{(by the definition of }S\text{)}\\
 &= f(2e) + 1 &\text{(since }f=S_e\text{),}\end{align}$$

which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that the total recursive functions cannot be recursively enumerable. In other words, we wish to show that $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \{n\}$ is total$\}$ is not recursively enumerable. Here, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\{n\}$ is the partial recursive function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ encoded by $n$.

Suppose on the contrary that $S$ is recursively enumerable. Then there exists a surjective total recursive function $g : \mathbb{N} \to S$.

Now define $h(x) = \{g(x)\}(x) + 1$. Then $h$ is a total recursive function. Let $n$ be a code of $h$. Then $n \in S$. Since $g$ is surjective, take some $m$ such that $g(m) = n$.

Then we see that $h$ is a total computable function. Therefore, there exist $n \in S$ such that $\{n\} = h$. Since $n \in S$, there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(m) = n$.

Then we see that $h(m) = \{g(m)\}(m) + 1$ by the definition of $h$. But we also see that since $h = \{g(m)\}$, we have $h(m) = \{g(m)\}(m)$. Therefore, we have $\{g(m)\}(m) + 1 = \{g(m)\}(m)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your time Mark, but I don't just want to show that the total recursive functions cannot be recursively enumerable (for this I agree that your argument is sound), but that the _surjective_ total recursive ones cannot be recursively enumerable. And in your argument, I dont see a reason why the function h you defined is itself surjective. I agree, by definition of enumeration, that g is surjective, but we need h to be surjective too. And that is where I find difficult to define such h leading to a contradiction by diagonalisation. I hope I am clear.